# I don't want array to do word splitting

Tags: bash

Below is my code. But bash is doing word splitting therefore I have failure. How to make my script so that there is no word splitting.

```
namaSensor=$(sensors | egrep "°C" | awk '{print $0}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
for sensor in $namaSensor
do
    if [ $(sensors | grep -c "$sensor") -ne 0 ]
    then
        currentTemperature=$(sensors | egrep "$sensor" | awk '{print $0}' | awk -F '+' '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-4 | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
        maxTemperature=$(sensors | egrep "$sensor" | awk '{print $0}' | awk -F '+' '{print $3}' | cut -c 1-4 | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
        if [ $currentTemperature -lt $maxTemperature ]
        then
            printf "current temperature is %d°C and the maximum allowed temperature is %d°C\n" "$currentTemperature" "$maxTemperature"
            printf "temperature is within the maximum allowed temperature\n"
            echo "$sensor"
        else
            printf "current temperature is %d°C and the maximum allowed temperature is %d°C\n" "$currentTemperature" "$maxTemperature"
            printf "temperature is more than the maximum allowed temperature\n"
            #exit 255
        fi
    fi
done.
```

This is the output of sensors for my unit.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.0Â°C  (crit = +111.0Â°C)
temp2:        +40.0Â°C  (crit = +111.0Â°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +34.0Â°C  (high = +87.0Â°C, crit = +105.0Â°C)
Core 0:         +31.0Â°C  (high = +87.0Â°C, crit = +105.0Â°C)
Core 1:         +22.0Â°C  (high = +87.0Â°C, crit = +105.0Â°C)
```

Please help

Comment: I think you need to also provide what you are expecting to see. Also the output of sensors being executed would help

Comment: So if there is both a maximum and a critical temperature, the maximum is used. If there is only a critical temperature, then that should be used?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have your array splitted as following:

Physical

id

0

and so on. To change this behaviour you need to change your Internal Field Separator (IFS) to a newline. So your code should look like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
nameSensor=$(sensors | egrep "°C" | awk '{print $0}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
for sensor in $nameSensor
do
    if [ $(sensors | grep -c "$sensor") -ne 0 ]; then
        currentTemperature=$(sensors | egrep "$sensor" | awk '{print $0}' | awk -F '+' '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-4 | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
        maxTemperature=$(sensors | egrep "$sensor" | awk '{print $0}' | awk -F '+' '{print $3}' | cut -c 1-4 | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
        if [ $currentTemperature -lt $maxTemperature ]; then
            printf "current temperature is %d°C and the maximum allowed temperature is %d°C\n" "$currentTemperature" "$maxTemperature"
            printf "temperature is within the maximum allowed temperature\n"
            echo "$sensor"
        else
            printf "current temperature is %d°C and the maximum allowed temperature is %d°C\n" "$currentTemperature" "$maxTemperature"
            printf "temperature is more than the maximum allowed temperature\n"
            #exit 255
        fi
    fi
done
```